# Dealing with Cookies in IE and Firefox

Tags: c#, asp.net, internet-explorer, cookies, firefox4

I have an application that creates a cookie when the user logs into the application.  The cookie is then read by subsequent pages and the user is allowed to continue processing on those pages if they are logged in (cookie exists).  When I run my app on IE 8.0 the cookie responds as I expect.  When I run my application through VS2008, the cookie responds as I expect.  When I run my application in Firefox 4.0, the cookie is not valid on my next page.

Here is code setup of my cookie

```
protected void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (CheckFields())
    {
        string strSQL;
        sqlUserInfo.SelectParameters.Clear();
        strSQL = "SELECT FirstName, LastName, Email FROM UserInfo WHERE Email=@email AND Password=@password";
        sqlUserInfo.SelectCommand = strSQL;
        if (txtEmail.Text != "")
        {
            sqlUserInfo.SelectParameters.Add("email", txtEmail.Text);
            sqlUserInfo.SelectParameters.Add("password", txtPassword.Text);
            DataView dv = (DataView)sqlUserInfo.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty);
            if (dv.Table.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                string welcomeMsg = "Welcome back " + dv[0][0] + " " + dv[0][1] + "!";
                HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("Email");
                cookie.Value = txtEmail.Text;

                DateTime dtNow = DateTime.Now;
                Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);

                lblMenu.Text = welcomeMsg + "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <a href='AcctInfo.aspx'>Update Account Info</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href='TextAlerts.aspx'>Create/Update Text Alerts</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href='graphSetup.aspx'>Graphing</a>";
                lblMessage.Text = "";
                btnLogin.Enabled = false;
                btnLogoff.Enabled = true;
            }
            else
            {
                lblMessage.Text = "Login Unsuccessful";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my code for the on load of my next page which is acctinfo.aspx.cs

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        cookie = Request.Cookies["Email"];
        if (cookie == null)
        {
            lblMessage.Text = "Not logged in. <a href='login.aspx'>Login</a>";
            lbLogoff.Visible = false;
        }
        else
        {
            EnableControls();
            string strSQL;

            sqlUserInfo.SelectParameters.Clear();
            strSQL = "SELECT FirstName, LastName, Email, Password, PhoneNumber, Provider FROM UserInfo WHERE Email=@email";
            sqlUserInfo.SelectCommand = strSQL;
            sqlUserInfo.SelectParameters.Add("email", cookie.Value.ToString());
            DataView dv = (DataView)sqlUserInfo.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty);
            if (dv.Table.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                oldPass = dv[0][3].ToString();
                oldPhone = dv[0][4].ToString();
                oldProvider = dv[0][5].ToString();
                if (!IsPostBack)
                {
                    txtPassword.Text = oldPass;
                    txtPassword2.Text = oldPass;
                    txtPhone.Text = oldPhone;
                    lstProvider.SelectedValue = oldProvider;
                    strMenu = "Welcome " + dv[0][0].ToString() + " " + dv[0][1].ToString() + "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href='TextAlerts.aspx'>Create/Update Text Alerts</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href='graphSetup.aspx'>Graphing</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";
                    lblMenu.Text = strMenu;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Cookies are enabled in Firefox because I can remove the code that saves the cookie from the file it's in, put it into a separate file, browse that file and then browse my AcctInfo and it works like expected.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Fiddler or other Http watcher tool to see what is actually send to/from browser. Code itself looks ok.

Comment: I agree with this. Use fiddler to see what's happening and how the cookies is outputted. The code looks fine. No reason why it shouldn't work

Comment: I installed Fiddler and here is what I noticed looking at the results.  When I run my app on IE, I get a GET for login.aspx and then a POST and cookie is set (in Response Headers section).  In FF I receive 2 GETs and then 1 POST where the cookie is set (in Response Headers)and then a GET (in Request Headers cookie is set)and in Response Headers the cookie has been cleared.  I'm not sure why there are multiple GETs that are occurring compared to only the 1 in IE?

Comment: Looks like original question itself is solved as non-issue: cookies work correctly - set with POST response by server and than send with next request(s) by browser. Server should not re-send cookies in responses unless you need to chage values and have code to do so.
You need to figure out where your extra requests come from and potentially ask new questions.
(consider creating smaller samples when you post code - your current ones include a lot of code that is not related to you problem).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your cookie is set to expire immeadiatly try the code below

```
HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("Email"); 
        cookie.Value = txtEmail.Text;

        DateTime dtNow = DateTime.Now;
        cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(1);
        Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
```

Comment: Unlikly - I don't see code that sets expiration in TacticalTS' sample... By default cookies are session cookies - so will not expire till browser open.

Comment: @Alexei - check out http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/questions/808831 esentially Firefox 4 will never remember cookie information by default, this is new for Firefox 4

Comment: Interesting, mine set to "Remember history" and I don't think I've ever changed it. But my 4.0 is upgraded through plenty of versions - could be that Firefox defaults to "never remember" for clean installs. 
@TacticalTS - check this setting out - could be your problem. Also making cookies persisten instead of session cookies is not necessary good fix - consider security vs what you need before changing.